# Automatically connect to one specific database using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database.  I've got the jdbc connector working and can view the MANY databases on the server.  Is there a way to tell SQL Developer that I only want to see the one specific database I'm interested in, and not all the others?

Thanks